# Why bootstrap 4.x "Disable totally Popper.js for Dropdown in Navbar"?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Dropdown menus inside the ".navbar" tag are not in `popper.js` control. Does anyone know why?

**bootstrap.js**

```
this._inNavbar = this._detectNavbar();
```

> line: 1674

```
// Disable totally Popper.js for Dropdown in Navbar

if (!this._inNavbar && usePopper) {
// ..........
}
```

> line: 1722

Comment: Did you ever get any clarification or a workaround for this?